# Need to use a callback on existing API to get the data asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use an existing API to get data asynchronously.

**Requires a Callback:**
*Existing API returns list of order changes*

```
$scope.NativeFactory.orderListChanges(cb)
```

My issue is if I get the data, and pass it to $scope.DocumentData.orders and then run a if statement below it the data isn't there at the time of the if statement because the if statement is running Synchronously.

ie:

```
 NativeFactory.orderListChanges(cb)

if (!$scope.DocumentData.orders.includes('milk')){

$scope.placeOrder('milk');

}
```

The orderListChanges hasn't detected that milk exists yet so I end up getting an invalid set of orders.

So how can I asynchronously wait for the milk to be available before running the if statement?

I have tried using a timeOut but the problem with that is that the database may not always be fast enough to deliver the data before the if statement is run.

Comment: Your question is not clear as it is not explaining the context. Let me ask few questions, Is there have any promise object returning by 'NativeFactory.orderListChanges' function ? what is 'cb' ? and what you are doing actually inside 'NativeFactory.orderListChanges' ?

Comment: Hi there.  NativeFactory.orderListChanges function is built into an API and it requests a call back to deliver most recent order changes data to.  I am using 'cb' as the parameter name for the callback to accept the data into.

Comment: @Gjustinj Put your logic inside the callback function. Something similar as this: NativeFactory.orderListChanges(function(){ if (!$scope.DocumentData.orders.includes('milk')){

$scope.placeOrder('milk');

}})

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, because it is used in several functions.  So I am looking at promises (resolve,reject) with try, catch and finally functions in it.  Is there a way without using a timeout to detect when a change has occurred to NativeFactory.orderListChanges?  Thanks!

Comment: Just another thing to add.   Right now $scope.orderListChanges function calls NativeFactory.orderListChanges($scope.orderListChanges_callBack) which then $scope.orderListChanges_callBack function accepts the object and returns it to a string with | separators that stores it into $scope.DocumentData.orderListChanges variable then in a separate function that is stating if (!$scope.DocumentData.orderListChanges.includes('milk')){
//At which point needs to have the order list changes correct or the if statement fires off wrong.
alert($scope.DocumentData.orderListChanges)

}

Comment: @Gjustinj Have you tried using watcher on object to get notified when object changes. For example: $scope.$watch('DocumentData.orders', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
    //Do anything with $scope.DocumentData.orders
});

Comment: Unfortunately the applications built in controller is preventing me from getting the data when I need it because it is requiring a call back.  So when I try to use my own it waits and then responds and by then  my code has already ran.  I found some $window calls that is allowing me to get the data when I need it.  Thank you everyone.